# iOS Swift: Building array from plist

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, plist

I'm having trouble building an array from a plist, but not just any array - it's an array of an array of dictionary objects.

Here is my plist xml file:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>firstName</key>
            <string>Jackie</string>
            <key>lastName</key>
            <string>Robinson</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>firstName</key>
            <string>Roger</string>
            <key>lastName</key>
            <string>Clemens</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>firstName</key>
            <string>Ichiro</string>
            <key>lastName</key>
            <string>Suzuki</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</array>
```

Path to the plist looks like this:

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Roster", ofType: "plist")
let pListArray = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path)
```

When I print pListArray, I get something like this:

```
(
        (
                {
            firstName = Jackie;
            lastName = Robinson;
        },
                {
            firstName = Roger;
            lastName = Clemens;
        }
   ),
        (
                {
            firstName = Ichiro;
            lastName = Suzuki;
        }
   )
)
```

When I hardcode the data and print out the arrays, I see the desired result of this:

```
[[Roster.Person, Roster.Person], [Roster.Person]]
```

I'm not sure if having the arrays within a array is bogging me down. I tried transforming the data to Person objects, but am getting a "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

```
for person in pListArray {
    Person(firstName: person["firstName"] as String, lastName: person["lastName"] as String)
}
```

Comment: 1. The two examples are different representation styles and that is a result of different display methods. The "print pListArray " is an accurate representation of the plist data in objects.

Comment: What is the question? What is the problem?

Comment: The end result is to display the data in a UITableView (i.e. Contacts app). I'm having problems creating the objects from the plist and populating them into an array. I need to turn the plist data into Person class objects with firstName and lastName properties.

Comment: Okay, I think I just needed some time to rest and sleep because I didn't get it at the time I posted the question. I'm pretty close to a solution.

I'm accessing the plist to create Person objects with this code:

`let personObject: AnyObject = pListArray.objectAtIndex(0).objectAtIndex(0)`
`var pListPerson = Person(firstName: personObject["firstName"] as String, lastName: personObject["lastName"] as String)`

I'm thinking to use some loops to append the objects to an array and appending each "section" array to the master array and voila! I have my UITableView already set up.